# ASP.NET Core publish with different env appsetting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Now I using dnu restore, dnu build and dnu publish -o {outputpath} to publish my ASP.NET Core website. I have appsettings.json and appsettings.STG.json how can I publish with different appsetting just like web.config before? I see some discuss on SO is use enviromentVariables but is this a good way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.Net 5/Core can use choose/combine different appsettings.json files during startup based on environment variables or other criteria you wish. But you can't "merge" different files into physical one (without any external tasks/tools).

Is this a "good" or "bad" way - completely depends on your scenario.

For storing connection strings (and other secrets) for dev/prod in different files this definitely a BAD idea, because you will store your production secrets in source code. Instead, use `AddEnvironmentVariables` and override you dev param values with production one "inside" production server.

Comment: Thx. I just want to check does there are other ways to do that in asp.net 5. I do not know how to do what you say "use AddEnvironmentVariables and override you dev param value..." but I will survey that. Thank you!

Comment: [Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BestPracticesForPrivateConfigDataAndConnectionStringsInConfigurationInASPNETAndAzure.aspx) you can find best practices for running in Azure. If you are deploying it to Azure.

Comment: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-the-built-in-providers is good start. Env. variables are very handy in clouds (like Azure), where you have no direct/easy access to host OS and servers are managed/restarted automatically. For on-premises deployments separate settings file (stored only on your server, not in source code) are more manageable.

Comment: But it didn't says hot to set EnvironmentVariables

Comment: For storing connection strings and secrets you should consider UserSecrets https://github.com/aspnet/usersecrets